# What is best approach to make large static binary available available through HTTP endpoint in Go over Google App Cloud?

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, go

Due to size of file repeatedly hitting deadline error (https://www.shiftedup.com/2015/03/12/deadline-errors-60-seconds-or-less-in-google-app-engine ) and cannot host these 3 binary files ( available on 3 endpoints ) over CDN.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine has two limits: 60 seconds and 32MB max per request. If you need to serve large files, you need to use Google Cloud Storage which supports files up to 5GB (June 2016). You can keep these files private and serve directly from the bucket to your client using a signed URL.

Comment: Thanks, files are well within 5 MB but hitting 60 seconds limit. What you suggest possibly here ? Any tuning / cache etc  (Already tried warmup)

Comment: Your response time should be ~1 second. Then it's up to the client to get the file. If you hit 60 seconds limit, something is wrong.